# Saving a .ebc file (EBCDIC)

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to save a .ebc file using the below code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
let $file := doc("\Text.ebc")
return
xdmp:save("\TestOutput.txt", $file,
<options xmlns="xdmp:save">
<output-encoding>ascii</output-encoding>   
</options>)
```

I want the EBCDIC content of the original file to be converted to ASCII while saving. I am getting weird output in the output file and not any ASCII content.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is inside the file, and how you inserted it into MarkLogic?

Comment: Using backslashes in document URIs is bad style. Instead of `\Text.ebc` I'd recommend `/Text.ebc` if you want directory structure, or simply `Text.ebc`. That won't fix your problem, but it may avoid other problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any text or xml document stored in MarkLogic is stored in UTF-8 encoding. So your document may not be EBCDIC right now, unless you stored it in binary format. You could check that using `xdmp:describe(doc($uri)/node())`: if it shows a binary node then it may be EBCDIC. If it shows text or XML, it's UTF-8. For now let's say you have a binary node containing EBCDIC codepoints.

The `xdmp:save` function takes an XML options element for its third argument, but any `output-encoding` element will only make sense for text or XML. Binary is binary: it has no known encoding, so `xdmp:save` doesn't know how to translate it into another encoding.

Let's create a very simple binary document with a single EBCDIC codepoint `0xC1`. That's equivalent to ASCII codepoint `0x41`: 'A'.

```
xdmp:document-insert(
  'test.ebc',
  binary { xs:hexBinary('C1') })
```

Let's confirm that we have a binary node in the new document:

```
xdmp:describe(doc('test.ebc')/node())
=> fn:doc("test.ebc")/binary()
```

Now let's try saving it:

```
xdmp:save(
  '/tmp/test-binary.txt',
  doc('test.ebc'),
  <options xmlns="xdmp:save">
    <output-encoding>ascii</output-encoding>
  </options>)
```

The contents:

```
$ od -x /tmp/test-binary.txt 
0000000 001a                                                        
0000001
```

If we leave off the `output-encoding` option it's still `C1`. All this just confirms that we can't rely on the `output-encoding` option with binary content.

So how can we convert EBCDIC to ASCII in MarkLogic? The best way would be to get the encoding right when we first inserted the document from wherever it came from. Functions like `xdmp:document-get` support input encoding options, and functions that support HTTP can use the `Content-Type` header.

But if you have a chunk of undecoded binary you can still handle it with https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:binary-decode

```
xdmp:binary-decode(
  doc('test.ebc'),
  'ebcdic-xml-us')
```

There seem to be about 100 variations of EBCDIC, so I just picked one. As expected the output is an `xs:string` `"A"`. You could now wrap that string in some XML or in a text node, and persist it with `xdmp:document-insert` or `xdmp:save`.

```
xdmp:save(
  '/tmp/test-binary.txt',
  text {
    xdmp:binary-decode(doc('test.ebc'), 'ebcdic-xml-us') },
  <options xmlns="xdmp:save">
    <output-encoding>ascii</output-encoding>
  </options>)
```

As expected the output file contains the letter `A` in ASCII. I could also have left off the `output-encoding` option to `xdmp:save`, and then it would be UTF-8. In this case that doesn't make any difference, but with real documents it might.

Comment: I tried with your solution and it is working fine for simple EBCDIC content files. But when the file contains any COMP or COMP -3 fields, it stops the conversion there itself.

Comment: This is the copybook of the file I am using.
       01  CUSTOMER-DATA.
           05 CUSTOMER-ID                    PIC 9(6).
           05 PERSONAL-DATA.
              10 CUSTOMER-NAME               PIC X(20).
              10 CUSTOMER-ADDRESS            PIC X(20).
              10 CUSTOMER-PHONE              PIC X(8).
           05 TRANSACTIONS.
              10 TRANSACTION-NBR             PIC 9(9) COMP.
              10 TRANSACTION OCCURS 0 TO 5
                 DEPENDING ON TRANSACTION-NBR.
                15 TRANSACTION-DATE         PIC X(8).

Comment: 15 FILLER REDEFINES TRANSACTION-DATE.
                    20 TRANSACTION-DAY       PIC X(2).
                    20 FILLER                PIC X.
                    20 TRANSACTION-MONTH     PIC X(2).
                    20 FILLER                PIC X.
                    20 TRANSACTION-YEAR      PIC X(2).
                 15 TRANSACTION-AMOUNT       PIC S9(13)V99 COMP-3.
                 15 TRANSACTION-COMMENT      PIC X(9).
File is getting encoded into ASCII only till 10 CUSTOMER-PHONE   PIC X(8). The next colomn i.e the COMP field is not getting encoded. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You're asking a new question. I don't think COMP or COMP-3 are part of EBCDIC as such. They are more like islands of binary data at designated positions in the text. I wouldn't expect an EBCDIC decoder to handler them, especially when there's no way to hand off the "copybook". You'll have to handle them elsewhere: I'd do it outside MarkLogic if possible. There's a python example at http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch34s05.html